# Move function to model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
I have this code:   

    report = report.Where(....)
    money = get_money report

 def get_money( report, count)
            price= Report
                .where('Month(date) =? and Year(date) =? ', 
                    report.date.month, report.date.year).first


            money= price.presence ? price.value.to_f / count: hardcoded_default__value
            return royalty_value
 end
```

How do I move this get_money function  to Report model?

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: Your code has errors and thus it's not clear what's your intention here. What's the purpose of `#get_money` and is `price` inside just one `Report` object, and `Report` has a `#value` method?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `get_money` method to app/models/report.rb:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_money(count)
    price = Report.where('Month(date) =? and Year(date) =? ', 
             report.date.month, report.date.year).first
             money= price.presence ? price.value.to_f / count: hardcoded_default__value
    return royalty_value
  end
end
```

(You're going to have to add the `royalty_value`) method as well since that variable isn't defined in the `get_money` function).

Then you can call the instance method on your report:

```
report = report.Where(....).take
money = report.get_money(count) # assuming the count variable is set
```